# How to include a file from .gitignore using git-clone?

Tags: git, vim

I cloned a vim plugin like this:

```
git clone git@github.com:szw/vim-ctrlspace.git
```

When I tried the plugin, it works but I cannot access the help file.

I check the `doc` folder and the file `ctrlspace.txt` is there, but the `tags` file is missing. Then I checked the `.gitignore` which it contains the `tags` file. How do I include this `tags` file when cloning?

Comment: I dont think you can. That's why it is included in .gitignore. Why dont you read their documentation on their github project page if you need help !?

Comment: the `tags` file is ignored so people working on the source code of vim-ctrlspace doesn't commit their locally generated tags file(a file generated by the ctags tool, that isn't related to any help files). Remember to regenerate the lep tags after installing plugins with `:helpt` in vim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this question is not a textbook X-Y problem I don't know what it is.

1. Vim plugins are usually *not* installed via `git clone` unless you use Pathogen or some similar runtimepath manager.
2. The `tags` file you are looking for *doesn't come with the plugin.* You must create it yourself.
3. Assuming you use Pathogen, you need to run the `:Helptags` command to index the plugin's documentation or `:helptags /path/to/directory/`

Your "problem" has *nothing* to do with Git *at all*.

Answer (score 2):

After installing a vim plugin, you might need to run the vim command

```
:helpt  ~/.vim/doc
```

(or whichever path you installed the plugin to, if it's not ~/.vim/)

As for your question, the tags file is in .gitignore so people working on the source code of vim-ctrlspace doesn't commit their locally generated tags file(a file generated by the [ctags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) tool, that isn't related to any help files).